# dbus-python how to return array of dictionaries

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, dbus, dbus-python

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and using Python Dbus. I want to return a list of dictionaries over DBus to my client but seem to only be able to return an array of strings. If I changed my dbus signature decorator to 'as{v}', I get an exception: "ValueError: Corrupt type signature". How can I return a list of dictionaries over DBus?

```
   @dbus.service.method("com.example.service.BtScanList", in_signature='', out_signature='as')
   def getScanList(self):
      btMsg("Starting BT Scan List...")
      # Populate device lists ( returns dictionary --> { 'mac_address' : xxx , 'name' : xxx }
      self.discoveredDevs = self.getScannedDevices()
      returnList = []
      for dev in self.discoveredDevs:
          returnList.append(dev["name"])
      return returnList
```

EDIT: This also does NOT work:

```
   @dbus.service.method("com.example.service.BtScanList", in_signature='', out_signature='a{sv}')
   def getScanList(self):
      btMsg("Starting BT Scan List...")
      # Populate device lists ( returns dictionary --> { 'mac_address' : xxx , 'name' : xxx }
      self.discoveredDevs = self.getScannedDevices()
      returnList = dbus.Array()
      for dev in self.discoveredDevs:
          btMsg(dev)
          returnList.append(dbus.Dictionary(dev, signature='sv'))
      return returnList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, answer is here:

```
   @dbus.service.method("com.example.service.BtPairedList", in_signature='', out_signature='aa{ss}')
   def getPairedList(self):
      btMsg("Starting BT Paired List...")
      # Populate device lists ( returns dictionary --> { 'mac_address' : xxx , 'name' : xxx }
      self.pairedDevs = self.getPairedDevices()
      returnList = dbus.Array()
      for dev in self.pairedDevs:
          btMsg(dev)
          returnList.append(dbus.Dictionary(dev, signature='sv'))
      return returnList
```

Comment: Could you please explain the meaning of 'aa{ss}' that you've used in out_signature.

Comment: 's': UTF-8 string.
'a': ARRAY
'{}': Array of key-value pairs.
Thus, 'aa{ss}': Array of key-value pairs where both the key and the value are strings.